# SQL in Access - Creating multiple tables from master where condition is changing string

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a table with a 1.1 million rows in Access. Three columns specify location. `Column1` contains 20 locations. `Column2` contains 70 locations, `Column3` contains a few thousand locations. `Column2` locations don't repeat accross `Column1` locations (unique `Column2` locations are found only in a single `Column1` location . I'd like to create 70 tables based on `Column2` locations. My issue, of course, is that I want to avoid creating 70 queries using `SELECT - INTO`

```
SELECT *
INTO new_table
FROM Mastersheet
WHERE Mastersheet.column2 = 'placename1';
```

Then I would need to repeat this with my second place name and so on. However these are text strings and so don't follow any specific order. I was thinking of perhaps creating a column with a number associated to every placename, and the try to create to a loop that would create a table every time that number increments, but I can't seem to find a way to do so...

So, beyond creating 70 different queries by hand, can I create a one query that does it all?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Splitting an existing table into 70 tables seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: I need to have users manipulate data in a Powerapp on Sharepoint and due to list limitations on Sharepoint...

Comment: AFAIK you can't create a single query that creates multiple tables in ms access. You can use VBA/macros to achieve this, though. But as noted, bad idea

Comment: @J.H. . . . Use views or queries with a `where` clause.